# React Native - Passing setState func as props to refresh screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I am new to React Native (using Expo Go), and I am trying to pass in props from the Profile screen to Edit Profile Screen using the navigate.navigate(). I then want to navigate back to the Profile Screen and want it to be refreshed so it has the updated information. It is not refreshing, and the states are not being updated in the Profile Screen. Here is a snippet of the codes.

Profile.js

```
const Profile = () => {
 const [name, setName] = useState(‘’)
 let navigation = useNavigate();
 navigation.navigate(“Edit”, {name: setName};
 return ( <div>{name}</div> )
}
```

Edit.js

```
const Edit = ({ setName }) => {
 let navigation = useNavigate()
 let newName = “John”;
 setName(newName); // does not update name in Profile
 navigatiom.navigate(“Profile”) // does not update profile
}
```

Comment: Why not to pass it as props? The `Edit` is not even a React component though.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change state directly you have to follow navigation `route`, see the below code:

Profile.js

```
const Profile = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  let navigation = useNavigation();

  const onPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Second', { updateName: (x)=>setName(x) }); //<---here you have to pass callback function
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Button
        onPress={onPress}
        title="Add title here"
        color="#841584"
        disabled={false}
      />
      <Text>{name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Edit.js

```
const Edit = ({ route }) => {  //<------here need to take route 
  let navigation = useNavigation();
  const onPress = () => {
    let newName = "John";
    route.params.updateName(newName);   //<-----this way to update.
    navigation.navigate("Home");
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Button
        onPress={onPress}
        title="Add title here"
        color="#841584"
        disabled={false}
      />
      <Text>{"name"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Let me know works or not.

Comment: When the state is updated through setName in the profile component, will this automatically render the updated Home page with the new state (i.e. name)

Comment: It is still not rendering on the Home Screen - after I update the props using setState functions, I need to refresh my Home Screen when navigating back